# Why is my ModelForm not showing the right settings?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two Model Forms, one for notification types and one for privacy settings. Both show the defaults and not what is saved in the database. How can I make the form show the choice that's stored in the database instead of the defaults? Example: Say the user chose a Direct Message privacy of "Friends and Followers". When they visit the privacy options page again after having saved the changes, it shows "Open" instead of reflecting what is in the database. I tried assigning the values saved in the database directly to the form when rendering the page when the request is `GET` but that didn't do anything, even though the debug print shows that the value of `form.dm_privacy` is indeed what's in the database, it still shows "Open".

Both forms work fine, the changes get saved and everything. I don't understand why it's not reflecting the changes though, is this just something that Model Forms do and not something I can change?

privacy_options.html

```
{% extends "accbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Privacy Options</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def privacy_options(request):
    """
    Holds all privacy options such as.. open/closed DMs, who can see profile/posts on profile
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PrivacyOptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Before saving:",request.user.dm_privacy, request.user.profile_privacy, request.user.included_in_find_friends) 
            user = request.user.username
            request.user.dm_privacy = form.cleaned_data['dm_privacy']
            request.user.profile_privacy = form.cleaned_data['profile_privacy']
            request.user.included_in_find_friends = form.cleaned_data['included_in_find_friends']
            request.user.save()
            print("After save:",request.user.dm_privacy, request.user.profile_privacy, request.user.included_in_find_friends) 
            return render(request, 'acc_manage/acc_nav.html', {'username':user})
    else:
        form = PrivacyOptionForm()
        form.included_in_find_friends = request.user.included_in_find_friends
        form.profile_privacy = request.user.profile_privacy
        form.dm_privacy = request.user.dm_privacy
        print("\n\n",form.dm_privacy, "\n\n") 
        return render(request, 'acc_manage/privacy_options.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing `form = PrivacyOptionForm()` to `form = PrivacyOptionForm(instance=request.user)`